# How do I use datetimepickers to find the difference between the entered start time and end time in hours? Visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetimepicker

I want to find the difference between the entered  Start Time and End Time using date-time pickers in C# windows forms applications using c#. The output should be given in hours.

Comment: You don't. You use two `DateTimePickers` to get two `DateTime` values. What you do with those values has nothing whatsoever to do with the controls. If you want to learn how to work with `DateTime` values then that's what you should be researching. The obvious place to start would be with the documentation for that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get two DateTimePickers and name them accordingly. Then go to property window and change their format to ”Time”. Below code is for the button which will trigger the calculation and show the output in a textbox.

```
    private void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan diff = dtpEndTime.Value - dtpStartTime.Value;
        int hours = diff.Hours + 1;
        txtShowOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(hours);
    }
```

Comment: That assumes that only times on the same day are being entered, which may or may not be the case. If the period may be greater than a day then you'd need to use `TotalHours`.

Answer (score 0):

**First, the accepted answer is wrong.** Lets assume both `DateTimePickers` contain the same date, with the time of `dtpStartTime` being 01:00:00 (exactly one o'clock in the morning) and `dtpEndTime` having a time of 07:00:00 (time for breakfast). Both times also land on whole seconds, so for this example we do not have to be concerned with fractions of a second.

So, what is the time difference between 01:00:00 and 07:00:00 (both are times at the same day)? It is precisely six hours. And yet, the code in the accepted answer produces an incorrect time difference of seven hours, obviously. So, why was that answer accepted, then? I can only guess that the asker prefers getting sometimes incorrect results over getting always correct results.

**To give a more meaningful answer,** it would first need to be decided how to deal with time differences that are not whole hours, like for example the difference between 01:15:00 and 03:07:47, for example. The question does not give clear directions about this, so i fill the void and define my own rule here: A time difference should be rounded up to the next larger whole hour if the fractional part of the time difference in hours is >= 30 minutes, otherwise the time difference should be rounded *down* to the next smaller hour. Which basically translates to:

```
TimeSpan diff = dtpEndTime.Value - dtpStartTime.Value;
int hours = (int) (Math.Abs(diff.TotalHours) + 0.5d);
```

Note that this is using floating point arithmetic, with the imprecision inherent in floating point operations applying here as well. Also note that by casting the resulting value to `int`, the maximum time difference in hours this code can handle is equivalent to about 245000 years, give or take. I hope that's not being a problem...